# What determines the ability to fast travel?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Whenever I need to travel for a quest, I hop in the Regalia and select the quest location I wish to drive to rather than walking the whole distance. A majority of the time, taking the scenic route is the only option available when driving. There are also times when I can fast travel to the quest locations, which are shown with `>>` to the right.

At first I thought this is determined by driving time, but sometimes I can fast travel a 3 minute drive and not a 9 minute drive and vice versa. Since the distance does not seem determine fast traveling, what does determines the ability to fast travel?

Comment: I believe it's to do with the availability of a nearby parking spot, garage or town. Worth bearing in mind as well if you have the upgrade for getting AP for driving, you won't earn AP for fast travelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to have done to be able to fast travel to specific locations is visit them before **with your car**. Thus, running to a location on foot will **not** unlock the ability to fast travel there. From [this article](http://twinfinite.net/2016/11/final-fantasy-xv-how-to-fast-travel/):

> If, however, you’ve been to that place before, you will then have the option to simply fast travel there for 10 Gil. So as long as you have your car and have been to a location, you can fast travel there for a very low price. That’s all there is to it. This allows players to explore the world and see the sights, but doesn’t force them to do it over and over again.

[Here](http://www.powerpyx.com/final-fantasy-xv-how-to-fast-travel/) is another article that supports the above claim that fast travel will be made available if you are at your car and have previously visited the location you want to fast travel to.

> After visiting an Outpost or Parking Spot for the first time it becomes available for fast travel. The black “fog” on the map will clear up when you’ve visited a location. You must interact with your car, the Regalia and then select the target location on the map. You will be asked if you want to fast travel (which costs 10 Gil) or drive there. Pay the price of 10 Gil and you’ll see a loading screen and instantly arrive at your target.

[Gamepur](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/25175-how-fast-travel-final-fantasy-xv.html) also supports that having previously visited a location will allow you to fast travel to it. In fact, it looks like even just driving past parking spots and rest stops will open up the option to fast travel.

> Fast Travel is possible at any parking point that has already been visited by the Regalia. By parking the car at a parking point in locations such as Hammerhead or Galdin, that area will then be available for travel to from then on. Rest stops and car parks by the road are made available for fast travel simply by passing by them.

---

However, there *are* certain points where you will either be unable to fast travel to certain locations. You're typically notified when this is the case.

Things that would prevent you from being able to fast travel aside from story-related reasons would include being near enemies or attempting to do so at night **prior to Ignis informing you that he is confident enough in your strength to be able to travel at nighttime.** Ignis should tell you this when you around level 25-30, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Wondercricket It may be that you're too close for it to be worth it? Not really sure; I've been away from FFXV for about a week now.

Comment: I know you won't be able to fast travel if there are enemies nearby or if you are trying to fast travel close to night time. I wonder if these have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Ramirez Now that I think about it, it would hit be hitting night time if I were to fast travel to the location and Ignis won't drive at night. This answer sounds more valid now

Comment: Not sure if I should post that as my own answer or just leave it as a comment.

Comment: @Wondercricket it's worth mentioning that once you get around level 25-30, Ignis will be confident in your strength and you can drive at night.